# Firestore returns two newIndex 0

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

Got a problem using Firetore, i'm trying to store and retrieve messages of conversations trough VueJS.

The moment i want to get my messages back with :

```
 // See last messages of the conversation
        vueLastMessages(where, type, value) {
            let that = this;
            let lesMessages = [];

            // console.log("Conv ID : ", value);
            db.collection(msg).where(where, type, value).orderBy('timestp', "asc")
                .onSnapshot(function (snapshot) {
                    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
                        if (change.type === "added") {
                            if (change.doc.data().timestp == Math.round(+new Date() / 1000)) {
                                console.log(change.doc.data().timestp);
                                console.log(Math.round(+new Date() / 1000));
                                lesMessages.push(change.doc.data());

                            }
                            else {
                                console.log(change);
                                console.log(change.doc.data().timestp);
                                // lesMessages.push(change.doc.data());
                                lesMessages.splice(0, 0, change.doc.data())
                            }
                        }
                        if (change.type === "modified") {
                            lesMessages.pop();
                            lesMessages.push(change.doc.data());
                            console.log("Modified message: ", change.doc.data());
                        }
                        if (change.type === "removed") {
                            lesMessages.pop();
                            console.log("Removed message: ", change.doc.data());
                        }
                    });
                });
            return lesMessages;

        }
    },
```

I find my messages but i got a problem :

The first message is not the first message anymore because Firestore returns me two items with the same newIndex :

```
{type: "added", doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot, oldIndex: -1, newIndex: 0}
{type: "added", doc: QueryDocumentSnapshot, oldIndex: -1, newIndex: 0}
```

But the timestamps are not in order at all :

1541169279
1539959608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, with the help of the Firestore help desk :

Do NOT call the

```
.onSnapshot(function (snapshot) {
```

function twice. At any cost. It will result in this strange bug.